# Create nested python dictionary and assign value inline?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I know that one can do something like this

```
d = {}
d['key1'] = {'Innerkey1':{'Response':'value','Type':'value2'}}
```

However, I need something like this

```
d['Key1']['Innerkey1'] = {'Response':'value','Type':'value2'}
```

as i'm consistently adding new innerkeys depending on various factors, and if I were to just do

```
d['Key1'] = {'NewInnerkey2': {'Response':'value','Type':'value2'}}
```

it overwrites and replaces innerkey1.

I suppose I can initialize d['key1'] first and use

```
.append({'NewInnerkey2': {'Response':'value','Type':'value2'}}),
```

however there are many different spots where a new primary or inner key may need to be initialized or not, and so it would lead to quite a bit of fluff  to check if whether it's been initialized or not and etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: See [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: Would that best way to use defaultdict be to turn                                            `dict1 = {key1':{'Innerkey1':{'Response':'value','Type':'value2'}}}`   and              
`dict2 = {key2':{'Innerkey2': {'Response':'value','Type':'value2'}}}`                        
into a list `[dict1, dict2]`                                                                                 and pass it to `finaldict = defaultdict(list)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
d = defaultdict(dict)
d['key1']['innerkey'] = {'Response':'value','Type':'value1'} # won't throw errors
d['key2']['innerkey2'] = {'Response':'value','Type':'value2'} # won't overwrite the value for innerkey
```

Comment: @Riley I think this is your use case, but I'm not sure